# CIFS VFS: Unexpected SMB signature

Tags: rhel, samba, cifs

When I login to server in Text mode the following Message appearing on one of Server

CIFS VFS: Unexpected SMB signature

We are using Redhat 5.6 64 bit.

Is this serious error and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would lead me to believe that you have either an `smbmount`, `mount.cifs`, or `mount -t cifs` command somewhere in you login configuration files. I'd look around in your .bashrc & .bash_profile files to start.

If you don't want to take the time to research the root cause you'd be OK in ignoring this message. It's basically saying that a SMB (Samba) mounting was attempted and failed.

A SMB mounting is when a Linux system mounts a directory/share from either a Windows system that's sharing one, or a Linux system running Samba, and is sharing out directories.